# Twilio Flex - Getting Agent properties after change of activity

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I need to get the agent properties that change the activity, is there a way to get the agent properties?

```
async init(flex, manager) {
  flex.Actions.addListener("afterSetActivity", (payload) => {
    // Would like to access agent properties here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only agent that can set the activity is the logged in agent which you can get using `manager.workerClient`.